# cannot add javascript file to cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i want to add my customer javascript file to my cshtml

i am working with mvc4

i tried these two ways

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Register.js")
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Register.js"></script>
```

nothing works.

i want to do this because i want to check for select change.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#selectRegisterType').on('change', function () {
        alert("ddddddd");
    });
});
```

also this is the code of the html

```
<select id="selectRegisterType">
    <option value="None">Select One</option>
    <option value="tenant">Tentant</option>
    <option value="Apartment Owner">Apartment Owner</option>
</select>
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Using MVC4 is really good and you should take advantage of the BundleCollection in your App_Start folder you'll see the BundleConfig.cs and there you can add your javascript and styles and others.

now what you need to write is

```
 public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
  {
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scrips/Register").Include(
             "~/Scripts/Register.js"));

   }
```

and in your footer tag inside your body tag

```
</footer>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Register")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>

< /html>
```

You could otherwise use some script to link directly to your script url like

```
</footer>
       <script type="text/javascript">

                var e = document.createElement('script');
                e.src = '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Register.js")';
                e.type = 'text/javascript';
                document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e);

        </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

WHERE do you put your script? As this looks like JQuery code, do you load JQuery before?

I put your code in JSFiddle, looks like it's working just fine as is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#selectRegisterType').on('change', function () {
        alert("ddddddd");
    });
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h2L6d/
(Duplicated your code here as I can't put a link to JSFiddle without some code)

It seems to me the only reason it would not be "working" is that you are not loading JQuery BEFORE calling your script. Usually, I load those js libraries below the footer of _Layout.cshtml:

```
       </footer>          
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/js") 
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.slidePanel.js"></script>            
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)        
    </body>
```

and scripts specific to a page in a script section, at the bottom of the cshtml view:

```
@section scripts {
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jstree")  
}
```

This way I am sure my js libraries are always loaded before my local page scripts. The script which is not in a bundle has been added later on, and should be bundled too.